# Azure devops assigment of roles rwx in ADLS gen2 container using powershell script path task in devops

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am facing one issue while assiging the roles to storage container rwx so that my data factory can 
    read data from adls gen 2. Below script is running fine using inline script in azure devops 
    powershell 
    script.But when I changed it to script from file path (location is github). I have put below script 
    in .ps1 extension already.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $resourcegroup_name,
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $factoryName,
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $storageaccount_name
 )

$principalID = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -Name 
$factoryName).identity.PrincipalId
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -AccountName 
$storageaccount_name
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$filesystemName = "adftransformation"
$dirname = "mfg/"
$dir = New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Directory - 
Permission r-x -Umask ---rwx---  -Property @{"ContentEncoding" = "UDF8"; "CacheControl" = "READ"}
$acl = (Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname).ACL
$acl = set-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityID $principalID -Permission r-x 
-InputObject $acl 
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Acl $acl
```

Error I am getting in devops pipline

> 2020-06-03T14:29:18.8399468Z ##[error]Cannot validate argument on
>   parameter 'Permission'. The 
>       argument "r-x" does not match the "([r-][w-][x-]){3}" pattern. Supply an argument that matches "([r-] 
>       [w-][x-]){3}" and try the command again.

I am not sure why this is happening while choosing script as file path same script is running fine in 
    inline script path

[image]

Comment: I have checked the ADSL gen2 doc and noticed that the `r-x` permission is valid. But from the error message, it seems that this couldn't be read. This issue seems to relate with the Azure Powershell script itself. Although I am not familiar with this script, I still want to give a little advice. You may  try to add quotation marks on `r-w` (e.g. -Permission "rw-").

Comment: I tried already that one and script is running fine in inline script. Only issue is that when same script I am taking from the scipt file path (git) it creates a issue with syntax rwx.

Comment: To narrow down this issue, you could directly use the `Azure Powershell` to run the  ps script file on **Azure**, then check if it could work. In this way, you can determine whether the cause of the problem is the script itself or azure devops file reading step.

Comment: Hello Kevin problem is with the syntax in permission -- rwx -- I removed the -- it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is the correct script  from Githubif you are taking as a file path.

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $resourcegroup_name,
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $factoryName,
 [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $storageaccount_name
 )
$principalID = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name -Name 
$factoryName).identity.PrincipalId
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup_name - 
AccountName $storageaccount_name
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$filesystemName = "fsname"
$dirname = "mfg/"
$dir = New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname 
-Directory -Permission rwxrwxrwx -Umask ---rwx---  -Property @{"ContentEncoding" = 
"UDF8"; "CacheControl" = "READ"}
$acl = (Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path 
$dirname).ACL
$acl = set-AzDataLakeGen2ItemAclObject -AccessControlType user -EntityID $principalID 
-Permission rwx -InputObject $acl 
Update-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname - 
Acl $acl
```